# How do i start MinIO Server with custom config in newer versions?

Tags: docker, minio

I'm trying to get up and running with Minio server. I've read their "server config guide" [here](https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/config/README.md), but there's one thing i don't get.

The guide says that previously you could put a config.json in the mino home dir you specify, but that it's now deprecated. You're instead supposed to use their client ('mc') to update configs via admin commands?

This seems very cumbersome to me, although i understand that you can pass in an entire json.config file via the mc client.

However, what if you have a docker container and want to start it with a custom config? I don't understand how you'd do that, and their "docker run" only contains info about how to start it with environment variables for custom username/password.

To me, it makes more sense to still have a config.json in the minio home dir, i don't totally get why they removed it.

If someone could help me understand the config better, i'd be a happier minio camper.